# Change data in form control Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-forms

I have an Angular v6 application. Here's my `FormGroup`

```js
stepperForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
  this.stepperForm = new FormGroup({
    apps: new FormControl(''),
    params: new FormControl('', SpecifyDetailsStepComponent.isValidJsonValidatorFn()),
  });
}
```

I have a method where I want to change the data in `formControl` `params`:

```js
const stringData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
this.stepperForm.setValue({
  apps: new FormControl(''),
  params: new FormControl(stringData, SpecifyDetailsStepComponent.isValidJsonValidatorFn()),
});
```

I have no error in the console but the data isn't changing at all.

#### Edit:

I need to be able to use the validator. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may simply do :

```
this.stepperForm.get('params').setValue(stringData);
```

And then to take immediate effect for validators.

```
this.stepperForm.get("params").updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do via Form: `this.stepperForm.get('FormControlName').setValue('WhateverData');`
Do via FormControl: `this.formControl.setValue('whateverData');`

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiple values at once using below one

```
this.stepperForm.setValue({
    apps: 'newValue',
    params: 'newValue',
});
```